# Approach to log in system using Node.js and Passport via Android

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am currently developing a web service that is using Node.js/ExpressJS and Passport for the login system. Everything is working fine on the web.

I would like to create an Android App that can be used to login to the server via httppost/JSON and get access to the user profile and all its variables.

Currently I am using a very stupid and unsecure approach.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Duan duan = ((Duan)getApplicationContext());

    String output = "";

    try {
        output = new LoginTask().execute(jsonURL).get();

        Log.v("JSON: ", output);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject;

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
        String username = jsonObject.getString("username");
        String user_id = jsonObject.getString("_id");

        duan.setUserId(user_id);
        duan.setUsername(username);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

As you can see, I am storing the _id and username field into a singleton that can be access across the application.

Is there a better and more secure way to program a log in system on android that works with Node.js and Passport?

Thanks,
Dennis